# Extracting the extracted with python

Tags: python, zip, extract

I have a zip file containing thousands of mixed .xml and .csv files. I used the following to extract the zip file:

```
import zipfile

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'c:\my.zip')

zip.extractall(r'c:\output')
```

Now I need to extract the thousands of individual zip files contained in the 'c:\output' folder. I am planning on concatenating just the .csv files into one file. Thank you for the help!

Comment: So you what you really have is a zipfile containing zipfiles?

Comment: Yes, it unpacks as zipped .csv and .xml files.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
import zipfile , os

zip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'c:/my.zip')

zip.extractall(r'c:/output')

filelist = []
for name in zip.namelist():
    filelist.append(name)



zip.close()
for i in filelist:


    newzip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'c:/output/'+str(i))
    for file in newzip.namelist():
        if '.csv' in file :
            newzip.extract(file,r'c:/output/')
    newzip.close()
    os.remove(r'c:/output/'+str(i))
```

Comment: EOL while running string literal

Comment: Also this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/extractzip.py", line 3, in <module>
    zip = zipfile.ZipFile(r'C:\ERCOT Pricing\Test')
  File "C:\Python33\lib\zipfile.py", line 912, in __init__
    self.fp = io.open(file, modeDict[mode])
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\ERCOT Pricing\\Test'

Comment: sorry the code has edited try it now . I have tried it on my pc and it worked.

Comment: the last error is from your pc not from the code . you have a Permission error. you have to change the Permission or try to extract in `D:/` instead of `C:/`

Comment: It works like a charm!! My mistake: I had the wrong lashes, it didn't recognize the str(i). It is also very fast! It completed over 8700 files in half the time it takes WinZip to complete 200 files! Thanks for the help!!!